# What is the easiest way to listen for and verify an AJAX call in a test environment?

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, testing

We have a JavaScript snippet that is installed on a cilent's page (think analytics/event tracking). We want to run this snippet's tests on as many browsers as possible (ie. Browserstack or similar). One thing we explicitly want to test is the JSON POST that it does with the event data. Right now, we're stubbing out the XMLHttpRequest calls and just verifying that they're called, but for completeness purposes we'd like to actually run the AJAX calls through the real browser stack, just in case some browsers do funky stuff we don't expect (like XDomainRequest in older IE).

Right now, all the tests are written in pure JavaScript that runs in the browser. If we stop stubbing the AJAX calls and actually send them through the browser, we will need to have some server listening to catch the calls and somehow communicate success or failure to the test library.

I could set up a simple server (probably NodeJS/Express) that has a single route for the AJAX call, but before I do that, I thought I'd ask if someone else has a better idea. Is there a tool specifically for this? Is there a way to avoid the server-side component completely, while still allowing the browser to actually POST the data *somewhere*?

Basically, I just want something that receives the POST and signals success of the test, and I want to write as little code as possible.

Comment: Wow...a downvote and vote to close in less than 30 seconds. That may be a record for me.

Comment: Well, you are kind of asking for a tool for this. So it's kind of against SO policies? Not that I did it. What if you use something like [this](https://requestb.in/)?

Comment: You can use jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net ,  plnkr http://plnkr.co or `console`

Comment: Yeah, that's really close to what I need, and exactly the kind of advice I was looking for. That's against SO policies? Guess I need to go brush up on how I'm supposed to use SO...

Comment: Not certain what actual Question is?